# Amcharts 3 Chart not Redrawing correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript, kendo-grid, amcharts

I am using Amcharts 3 for our Charts and I am working with adding/removing Guides on the charts dynamically. If a user selects a Checkbox then it adds 2 Guides to the chart but if a user either Unselects that checkbox or checks another Checkbox I am wanting the Guides to be removed. So far I have the Guides adding correctly however when when a User Selects/Unselects another checkbox, the Guides are not being removed for some reason.

This is the Code that I am using to add/remove the Guides:

```
         let posReportTypeChart = chartingManager.getChartById("posReportType");
          // If only one Checkbox is Selected, add the Guides to the chart
            if (this.selectedQrCount == 1) {
                let selected = qrGridEvents.grid.dataSource.data().filter(x => x.IsSelected == true);
                let guideEffDate = this.getNewGuide(selected[0].EffectiveDate);
                let guideEndDate = this.getNewGuide(selected[0].EndDate);
                posReportTypeChart.guides.push(guideEffDate);
                posReportTypeChart.guides.push(guideEndDate);
                this.reDrawPOSReportTypeChart(posReportTypeChart);
            }
            else if (posReportTypeChart.guides.length > 1) {
                posReportTypeChart.guides = [];
                this.reDrawPOSReportTypeChart(posReportTypeChart);
            }

            // This is the function that I am using to redraw the chart. For some reason it is
               adding the Guides fine but whenever I go to remove the Guides this isn't working.
            private reDrawPOSReportTypeChart = (chart: any) => {
                  chartingManager.charts[3] = chart;
                  chart.dataProvider = chartingManager.itemChartingData;
                  chart.validateNow(true, false);
                  chart.invalidateSize();
                  chart.legend.validateNow();
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You need to use chart.categoryAxis.addGuide to add a Guide and then just use chart.categoryAxis.guides = [] to clear the Guides. Just make sure you use chart.validateData() after each call to add or remove the Guides to redraw the chart.